# vars not working after rewrite_by_lua_block

Tags: if-statement, nginx, lua, set

see the codes below:

```
set $RUN_VERSION 'current';
rewrite_by_lua_block {
    ....
    ngx.var.RUN_VERSION = 'new'
}
echo $RUN_VERSION;
--------------------
visit the server: new
It seems work.
```

========================================================

```
set $RUN_VERSION 'current';
rewrite_by_lua_block {
    ....
    ngx.var.RUN_VERSION = 'new'
}
echo $RUN_VERSION;

if ($RUN_VERSION = "new"){
    echo "11111";
}
if ($RUN_VERSION = "current"){
    echo "22222";
}
--------------------
visit the server: 22222
```

Problems in the 2nd case:
1. echo $RUN_VERSION; shows nothing.
2. It was supposed to display 11111

Comment: It says *somewhere* in the docs of the lua-nginx-module that `if`s always run **before** the `rewrite_by_lua_block`. There's an option to change that behavior though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix is turning on [`rewrite_by_lua_no_postpone`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#rewrite_by_lua_no_postpone) in your nginx configuration.

I assume there's *some* reason (maybe performance?) why this is disabled by default.